# Selecting features of one layer based on another layer

Tags: qgis-3, pyqgis-3

I have a polygon layer A, then a new layer is created by applying minimum bounded boxes algorithm and then I selected those features in which height and width of bounded boxes is less than 150 and saved it in another layer named B. Now, I want the corresponding original polygons from layer A whose bounding boxes are saved in B into an another layer. Number of features is around 41k in layer A and 40k in layer B. Can this be achieved? I am using qgis 3.8

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried join attributes by field value but it is doing something strange, after that I tried one more method, I passed the id of the original polygons while creating bounded boxes. So the task just reduces to filter out all of the ids from the attribute table of layer A which are in layer B. Basically intersection of 2 columns, and then selecting the intersected part and saving saving it in new layer

Comment: How about `select by location`, based on the bounding boxes?

Comment: No luck by that method too, I selected "EQUAL" from "where the features" selection list. Result is NULL selected value, as it should be because feature are not equal, only the values of one field in the attribute table matches with the some values of one filed in another layer's attribute table. The result is NO selected polygons.

Comment: Try using extract by location with intersect predicate. Extract A that intersects B.